# How can I save a list in google-app-engine database?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have the following code that is not working properly.
testprovincia exist on data base and the partidos variable is a list that I am sure is not empty but is never persisted too.

```
mgr = getPersistenceManager();
Query query = mgr.newQuery(Provincia.class);
query.setFilter("name == nameParam");
query.declareParameters("String nameParam");
List<Provincia> results = (List<Provincia>) query.execute("testprovincia");
Provincia prov = results.get(0);

insertPartidos(partidos);

prov.setPartidos(partidos);
mgr.makePersistent(prov);
query.closeAll();
mgr.close();
```

InsertPartidos method:

```
private void insertPartidos(List<Partido> partidos){
    for (Partido partido : partidos) {
        log.info(partido.getName());
        mgr.makePersistent(partido);
    }
}
```

The question is why I never see the list I added to prov variable on the database? Is allways empty.

Here are my classes:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Provincia {

    public Provincia(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    @Persistent
    private String name;
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "provincia")
    @Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus",key="list-ordering", value="name asc"))
    private List<Partido> partidos;

    public Key getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Key id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Partido> getPartidos() {
        return partidos;
    }
    public void setPartidos(List<Partido> partidos) {
        this.partidos = partidos;
    }
}

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Partido {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    @Persistent
    private String name;

    @Persistent
    private Provincia  provincia;

    public Partido(){
    }

    public Partido(Key id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Partido(Key id, String name, Provincia prov) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.provincia = prov;
    }

    public Partido(String name, Provincia prov) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.provincia = prov;
    }

    public Key getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Key id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Provincia getProvincia() {
        return provincia;
    }

    public void setProvincia(Provincia provincia) {
        this.provincia = provincia;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using the other way of updating.  If testprovincia already exists, using the method described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata?hl=it#Updating_an_Object) might do the trick for you.  Instead of using makepersistent, grab your data with the persistence manager and straight update it.

That or use standard datastore's db (or ndb) puts, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore)?  Do you REALLY need the JDO?

Comment: I add more information maybe I something wrong with the previus inserts that are using the same mgr variable to persist. I change the code like you described but I had the same situation.

Comment: You didn't use the right method.  I was talking about the one where they don't use makePersistent but grab the object by ID with the persistence manager, and then just update the object.  The first link I provided, the first snippet of code you'll see.

Comment: If I use for example Provincia prov = mgr.getObjectById(Provincia.class, "province name"); I can´t retrieve the entity, an exception is trowed

Comment: No, but I changed the code again to convert the name to a key, but you can't put a string as a key and have childrens in your class at the same time, you get an exception. So I will be back the old code and here I must ask, becouse is crazy, I have to load first the province from the query and the load the same province again with the code you point to me? And finaly try to update the province with the list...

Comment: If you don't have the province up front and that is your key, yes that might be a way to do it... it does sound a bit circular, but it's to make you try that other PM method.